# How to convert 3d powered flash design to css/html?

Tags: css, 3d

About 6-7 years ago I made some web sites with flash, I made 3d rendered scenes in it. As you know these years flash has been dead. 
I'm giving an example page:
http://ugurtekdal.com/temp-portfolio/sora-kozmetik/

My question is, how can I make such design without using flash? How can I make it with css/html? I want to know information about hover effects of those products in example page.

Thank you.

Comment: HTML and CSS alone won't do the deal. You will have to study JavaScript and canvas. Maybe use some library for rendering.

Comment: I dont want to draw graphics with Javascript/canvas,  I already have my graphics (3d rendered files).

Comment: Yes, I've understood what you said. What I mean is you will have to draw the resulting images from year 3D package on canvas to simulate the animations. You can try [Adobe Edge](http://html.adobe.com/edge/animate/). It has an interface similar to Flash and will export animations in HTML, JS and CSS.